# solve $9x^7\equiv67\pmod{149}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How to solve: ${9x^7\equiv67\pmod{149}}$

I've already found out that $x^7\equiv24\pmod{149}$ by using Extended Euclidean Algorithm
But I have no clue what to do next. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Hint: $149$ is prime, and $148$ is relatively prime to $7.$

Comment: Hint 2: maybe you can find a number $k$ such that $(x^7)^k\equiv x\pmod{149}$ for all $x$. Then you have that $24^k=x^{7k}=x$ and you have found $x$ :D

Comment: I think I got it: By Euler's theorem, I could know that 
$x^{t} ≡ x^{t\:mod\:Φ(149)}\:(mod\:149)$
, so if I let inverse of $7(mod\:148)$ be k , I could get: $x^{7k} ≡ x^{7k\:mod\:Φ(149)} ≡ x^1\:(mod\:149) $

Comment: @GordonZ I updated the dupe link to one that is much more pertinent.